# Bind attribute does not have `Exclude`, is there an work around?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

In ASP.Net Core MVC, the `Bind` attribute seems to not have the `Exclude` property anymore. Assuming I have 20 properties in my model, and I only want to exclude a single filed from the model for the edit function for example, it will be really inconvenient to type the name of the 19 properties in order to exclude that single field.

The point of the question is to find if Microsoft has added any other attribute for this purpose or there's something hidden from my view that can do this.

Answer (score 1):

Similarly to [`BindAttribute`](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/18785dbed6ef63990f1732c509a19cf8ef533cb5/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/BindAttribute.cs), you have to implement the `IPropertyFilterProvider` interface.

Something like this:

```
    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Parameter, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
    public class ExcludeBindAttribute : Attribute, IModelNameProvider, IPropertyFilterProvider
    {
        private static readonly Func<ModelMetadata, bool> _default = (m) => true;

        private Func<ModelMetadata, bool> _propertyFilter;

        public string[] Exclude { get; }

        public string Prefix { get; set; }

        public ExcludeBindAttribute(params string[] exclude)
        {
            var items = new List<string>();
            foreach (var item in exclude)
            {
                items.AddRange(SplitString(item));
            }

            Exclude = items.ToArray();
        }

        public string Name
        {
            get { return Prefix; }
        }

        public Func<ModelMetadata, bool> PropertyFilter
        {
            get
            {
                if (Exclude != null && Exclude.Length > 0)
                {
                    if (_propertyFilter == null)
                    {
                        _propertyFilter = (m) => !Exclude.Contains(m.PropertyName, StringComparer.Ordinal);
                    }

                    return _propertyFilter;
                }
                else
                {
                    return _default;
                }
            }
        }

        private static IEnumerable<string> SplitString(string original)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(original))
            {
                return Array.Empty<string>();
            }

            var split = original.Split(',').Select(piece => piece.Trim()).Where(piece => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(piece));

            return split;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Good fix @rocky. One questions, what is the `Prefix` property used for? I don't see it is required by any interface, just want to be sure it is not used by the model binder or something else befrore removing it.

Comment: Not exactly sure why I included it...maybe it was copied from somewhere else. Anyway, only the `Name` property is required by one of the interfaces so it should be safe to drop it. You'll find out soon enough if you test it ;)

Comment: @bcngr Prefix is helpful when all (or most of) your model property names start with some prefix (like 'udg_..', which might happen with Entity Framework based entities that double as view models (happens when applications are forced to be aligned with some legacy database tables.). By using the Prefix property one would not need to type names of properties that all start with "udg_" (following the example here) but instead enumerate clear property names ("Id, Password", vs. "udg_Id, udg_Password"). So @rocky would have to change to `Exclude.Contains(string.Concat(Prefix, m.PropertyName),..);`

Comment: if I have public async Task<IActionResult> Update([Bind(Exclude = "Id")] ParticipantInfoUpdateModel model)
How it is used? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I am not exactly sure where you want to exclude that single field. If you have an action method that gets a parameter of the type of a viewmodel class containing 20 properties and you want to exclude one of those properties from model binding you can use [BindNever] annotation on that property (please have a look at [Model Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/model-binding?view=aspnetcore-2.1)).

Thus your action method gets a viewmodel with that annotated property always being null - a user cannot pass a value for that property because it won't be processed for model binding.

Comment: well, a quite regular example might be using a view model class in Create and Edit views to avoid repetition, in such a case one might want to exclude the key property (Id) when creating and including it when editing. I am not saying this is a quintessential example, but an example nonetheless.

Comment: Good point! In this case I would create two View Model classes: A Create view model class with all properties except the ID and then by inheritance (or composition if you favor that although in this case I would stick with inheritance) an Edit view model with a single additional property ID. In the action methods one or the other view model is used. This would have the advantage that you can't forget the 'Exclude' so easily, because you have to make a clear decision for one of the two view model classes. This makes the whole thing less error-prone.